# equivalent JSON request for _search?q:value in elasticsearch

Tags: json, url, syntax, elasticsearch

Is there anyway to ask ES to explain a URL query like this one:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search?q=something
```

Elasticsearch is returning undesired documents and don't know why.

Is there a way of changing url request into a JSON request like:

Note: syntax from marvel plugin.

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search
{ explain : true,
  query : {
    "q" : "something"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answers my own question:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search
{
  explain : true,
  query : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "something"
    }
  }
}
```